# h5py problem - driver lock request failed - how to fix? (under WSL Ubuntu)

Tags: python, h5py, hdf

I am trying to use the h5py (https://pypi.org/project/h5py/) package to handle the data of datasets in that format.

I am using a side library to write datasets in that format, it uses the h5py.

I got the following error when I tried to use their code:

> driver lock request failed\n  File "H5FDsec2.c", line 1002, in
> H5FD__sec2_lock\n    unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message =
> 'Resource temporarily unavailable'\n\nEnd of HDF5 error back
> trace\n\nUnable to open/create file 'samples_file.hdf5'

it creates a hdf file in the directory I am working but it seems that it's locked and it can't be written.

What is the problem?

How to fix or maybe any additional information is needed?

Some information about the configuration I have :

```
{'platform': 'Linux',
 'platform-release': '5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2',
 'platform-version': '#1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023',
 'architecture': 'x86_64',
 'hostname': 'note-4',
 'ip-address': '127.0.1.1',
 'mac-address': '00:15:5d:aa:8e:c1',
 'processor': 'x86_64',
 'ram': '15 GB'}
```

*UPDATE:*

I will show you a small part of code that is running here:

```
if use_hdf5:
    # check for exiting test case file
    check_case_file(case_file)
    h5f = h5py.File(case_file, "a")
    # loop over given number of samples
    for i in range(min(dataset_range), max(dataset_range)):
        sample_group = f'sample_{i}'
        if sample_group in h5f:
            if ('exp_pw' in h5f[sample_group]) and ('theo_pw' in h5f[sample_group]) and ('theo_par' in h5f[sample_group]):
                if overwrite:
                    sample_and_write(case_file, i, particle_pair, experiment, solver, open_data, fixed_resonance_ladder, vary_Erange, use_hdf5)
                else:
                    samples_not_being_generated.append(i)
            else:
                sample_and_write(case_file, i, particle_pair, experiment, solver, open_data, fixed_resonance_ladder, vary_Erange, use_hdf5)
        else:
            sample_and_write(case_file, i, particle_pair, experiment, solver, open_data, fixed_resonance_ladder, vary_Erange, use_hdf5)
    h5f.close()
```

In the function that writes file..:

```
def sample_and_write(case_file, isample, particle_pair, experiment, solver, open_data, fixed_resonance_ladder, vary_Erange, use_hdf5):

...

    # write data
    if use_hdf5:
        exp_pw_df.to_hdf(case_file, f"sample_{isample}/exp_pw")
        ...
        f = h5py.File(case_file, 'a')
        if 'exp_cov' in f[f"sample_{isample}"].keys():
            del f[f'sample_{isample}/exp_cov']
        else:
            pass
        f.create_dataset(f'sample_{isample}/exp_cov', data=CovT)
        f.close()
    else:
        exp_pw_df.to_csv(os.path.join(case_file,f'sample_{isample}','exp_pw'), index=False)
        theo_pw_df.to_csv(os.path.join(case_file,f'sample_{isample}','theo_pw'), index=False)
```

Comment: Did you close the file? HDF5/h5py locks the file when it is opened for write access. If you don't close it properly, the process doesn't release the lock and the file remains locked. The same thing can happen when a program exists unexpectedly.

Comment: Well, show a minimum reproducible example. Show the code, link to the library if it is OSS

Comment: The problem is that I am using a library that uses h5py... just to create and manage datasets.. I will update the code/question - but really I don't know how it can help...

Comment: You are opening the file located at `case_file` yourself and the library is trying to open it too in `sample_and_write`. That's it.